# I can't call the function using jdbc, but if it is pipelined, then everything works

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, spring-jdbc

I using spring jdbc and oracle 12.

I can't get a response from the package function. But if I use exactly the same function but with the pipeline everything works.

Created a package and declared 2 functions in it. Both of them take a number as input, and output a table of pl/sql records. The difference in the function is that one is pipelined and the other is not

The declaration is:

```
type o_client is record(subs_id     NUMBER);
type t_client is table of o_client;
    
function piplined_func   (p_subs_id in NUMBER)  return t_client pipelined;

function no_piplined_func   (p_subs_id in NUMBER)  return t_client;
```

The body is:

```
function piplined_func(p_subs_id in NUMBER) return t_client PIPELINED AS 
v_pipe o_client;
BEGIN 
    FOR ids IN 1..10 LOOP
        v_pipe.subs_id := ids;
        PIPE ROW(v_pipe); 
    END LOOP;
    return ;
END;

function no_piplined_func   (p_subs_id in number)  return t_client  AS 
    l_tab t_client;
    v_pipe o_client;
BEGIN
    l_tab := t_client();
    FOR ids IN 1..10 LOOP
        v_pipe.subs_id := ids;
        l_tab.extend;
        l_tab(l_tab.last) := v_pipe;
    END LOOP;
    return l_tab;
END;
```

The first function is work correct:

```
System.out.println("Pipelined");
Processor processor = new Processor(oracleDataSource);
final String query = "select * MY_CATALOG.piplined_func(:p_subs_id)";
SqlParameterSource inputParams = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_subs_id", 1);
List<Wrapper> result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, inputParams, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Wrapper.class));
for (Wrapper wrapper : result) {
    System.out.println(wrapper.toString());
}
```

```
Out:
Wrapper{subs_id=1}
Wrapper{subs_id=2}
Wrapper{subs_id=3}
```

The second function is not work correct:

```
System.out.println("Not Pipelined");
Processor processor = new Processor(oracleDataSource);
final String query = "select * from MY_CATALOG.no_piplined_func(:p_subs_id)";
SqlParameterSource inputParams = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_subs_id", 1); 
List<Wrapper> result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(query, inputParams, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Wrapper.class));
for (Wrapper wrapper : result) {
    System.out.println(wrapper.toString());
}
```

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select * from sa_db_test.no_piplined_func(?)]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

I tried to use SimpleJdbcCall in the same way, but also unsuccessfully.

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(oracleDataSource)
    .withSchemaName("MY_SCHEMA")
    .withCatalogName("MY_CATALOG")
    .withProcedureName("no_piplined_func")
    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
    .declareParameters( new SqlParameter("p_subs_id", Types.NUMERIC),);
SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("p_subs_id", 1);
Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call MY_SCHEMA.MY_CATALOG.NO_PIPLINED_FUNC(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
> PLS-00221: 'NO_PIPLINED_FUNC' is not a procedure or is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `RECORD` is a PL/SQL **ONLY** data-type that cannot be used in SQL statements.

A `PIPELINED` function is designed to be used in SQL statements and despite you declaring that it returns a table of `RECORD` data types, it does not actually do that and, instead, creates equivalent SQL data-types (i.e. `OBJECT` data-types) that can be used in SQL statements.

If you want both to work then declare `o_client` and `t_client` in the SQL scope using:

```sql
CREATE TYPE o_client IS OBJECT (subs_id NUMBER);
CREATE TYPE t_o_client IS TABLE OF o_client;
```

Then you can use SQL data-types and not PL/SQL data-types:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE pkg IS
  type r_client is record(subs_id     NUMBER);
  type t_client is table of r_client;
    
  function pipelined_func    return t_client pipelined;

  function no_pipelined_func return t_client;

  function no_pipelined_func_obj return t_o_client;
END;
/
```

and the body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY pkg IS
  FUNCTION pipelined_func
  RETURN t_client PIPELINED
  AS 
    v_pipe r_client;
  BEGIN 
    FOR ids IN 1..10 LOOP
        v_pipe.subs_id := ids;
        PIPE ROW(v_pipe); 
    END LOOP;
  END;

  FUNCTION no_pipelined_func
  RETURN t_client
  AS 
    l_tab  t_client;
    v_pipe r_client;
  BEGIN
    l_tab := t_client();
    FOR ids IN 1..10 LOOP
      v_pipe.subs_id := ids;
      l_tab.extend;
      l_tab(l_tab.last) := v_pipe;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_tab;
  END;

  FUNCTION no_pipelined_func_obj
  RETURN t_o_client
  AS 
    l_tab  t_o_client := t_o_client();
  BEGIN
    FOR ids IN 1..10 LOOP
      l_tab.extend;
      l_tab(l_tab.last) := o_client(ids);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_tab;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pkg.no_pipelined_func();
```

Fails with:

> ```
> ORA-00902: invalid datatype
> ```

But:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pkg.pipelined_func();
```

and

```sql
SELECT * FROM pkg.no_pipelined_func_obj();
```

Both output:

> | SUBS_ID |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 3 |
> | 4 |
> | 5 |
> | 6 |
> | 7 |
> | 8 |
> | 9 |
> | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d01d3a55835b9d683f1449dc7a207151)*